# flexbox needs overflow in IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I have a flexbox which should be overflowed by its children to the left and to the right side. Here is my code for this solution. It works in all browsers properly but **it doesn't work in IE 11** (children overflow flexbox to the right side only).

I tried to solve this problem with `overflow-x:visible` for the section and the list, but it doesn't work. The `overflow-x` property in the body hides the horizontal scroll and it's OK for my task. As you can see, I've already used autoprefixer for my CSS but I didn't find the solution in prefixes. Is this a special behavior of IE flexbox overflow? :)

So my questions are why my solution doesn't work in IE 11 and what can I do to solve this problem?

```css
body{
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #999;
}

.visually-hidden{
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

.testimonials{
  position: relative;
  height: 576px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-image: url("../img/quotes.png"),
  url("../img/quotes-reversed.png"),
  url("../img/worldmap.png"),
  url("../img/worldmap.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 115px 60px,
  1140px 380px, -290px 205px, 530px -270px;
  background-size: auto, auto, auto, auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: visible;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.reviews-catalog{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin-top: 160px;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.review{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 470px;
  height:243px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px 0px rgba(0, 153, 255, 0.1);
          box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px 0px rgba(0, 153, 255, 0.1);
}

.review:first-of-type{
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.review:last-of-type{
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.review:first-of-type::before,
.review:last-of-type::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.review:first-of-type .review-photo,
.review:last-of-type .review-photo{
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.review:first-of-type:hover .review-photo,
.review:last-of-type:hover .review-photo{
  opacity: 1;
}

.review:first-of-type:hover::before,
.review:last-of-type:hover::before{
  opacity: 0;
}

.review-photo{
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -45px;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
      -ms-flex-order: -1;
          order: -1;
}

.review-author{
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.review-content{
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 370px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="testimonials">
      <h2 class="visually-hidden">Other reviews</h2>
      <ul class="reviews-catalog">
        <li class="review">
          <h3 class="review-author">Kevin Smith,</h3>
          <p class="role">Pediatrics student</p>
          <p class="review-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <img class="review-photo" src="img/kevin.png" alt="kevin's avatar" width="90" height="90"/>
        </li>
        <li class="review">
          <h3 class="review-author">Kevin Smith,</h3>
          <p class="role">Pediatrics student</p>
          <p class="review-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <img class="review-photo" src="img/kevin.png" alt="kevin's avatar" width="90" height="90"/>
        </li>
        <li class="review">
          <h3 class="review-author">Jane Lambert,</h3>
          <p class="role">Psychiatry student</p>
          <p class="review-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <img class="review-photo" src="img/jane.png" alt="jane's avatar" width="90" height="90"/>
        </li>
        <li class="review">
          <h3 class="review-author">Jane Lambert,</h3>
          <p class="role">Psychiatry student</p>
          <p class="review-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <img class="review-photo" src="img/jane.png" alt="jane's avatar" width="90" height="90"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

Comment: In left-to-right writing mode, there's no such thing as overflow to the left. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38830775/3597276

Comment: It works in G-Chrome, FFox, etc. and there is overflow to the left without any changes of writing mode. I don't think that overflow direction changes like `rtl` are the solution, because it will cause another issues to do (and then it will overflow to the left but not to the right, the same problem). I simply need to correct the existing solution for IE 11.

Comment: It's possible to render a scrollbar that goes left. My point is that such a function is *not an overflow*. It's just specialized scrolling. Overflow can only occur in the direction of the writing mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the flex properties from the `.testimonials` and add these 3, you will get the same result cross browsers, where the items *center* and *overflow* equally to the left/right

```
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
```

This works like that, that the `inline-block` make it size by content, the `left: 50%` (together with the already set `position: relative`) position its left edge in the middle of its parent, in this case the `body`, and the `transform: translateX(-50%)` will move it 50% of its own width to left.

Stack snippet

```css
body{
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Open Sans", "Arial", sans-serif;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #999;
}

.visually-hidden{
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

.testimonials{
  position: relative;
  height: 576px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  background-image: url("../img/quotes.png"),
  url("../img/quotes-reversed.png"),
  url("../img/worldmap.png"),
  url("../img/worldmap.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 115px 60px,
  1140px 380px, -290px 205px, 530px -270px;
  background-size: auto, auto, auto, auto;
  /*
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: visible;
  -webkit-box-align: start;
      -ms-flex-align: start;
          align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  */
  display: inline-block;                    /*  added  */
  left: 50%;                                /*  added  */
  transform: translateX(-50%);              /*  added  */
}

.reviews-catalog{
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin-top: 160px;
  overflow-x: visible;
}

.review{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 470px;
  height:243px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px 0px rgba(0, 153, 255, 0.1);
          box-shadow: 0px 3px 18px 0px rgba(0, 153, 255, 0.1);
}

.review:first-of-type{
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.review:last-of-type{
  margin-right: 0px;
}

.review:first-of-type::before,
.review:last-of-type::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.review:first-of-type .review-photo,
.review:last-of-type .review-photo{
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.review:first-of-type:hover .review-photo,
.review:last-of-type:hover .review-photo{
  opacity: 1;
}

.review:first-of-type:hover::before,
.review:last-of-type:hover::before{
  opacity: 0;
}

.review-photo{
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: -45px;
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
      -ms-flex-order: -1;
          order: -1;
}

.review-author{
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.review-content{
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 370px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<section class="testimonials">
      <h2 class="visually-hidden">Other reviews</h2>
      <ul class="reviews-catalog">
        <li class="review">
          <h3 class="review-author">Kevin Smith,</h3>
          <p class="role">Pediatrics student</p>
          <p class="review-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <img class="review-photo" src="img/kevin.png" alt="kevin's avatar" width="90" height="90"/>
        </li>
        <li class="review">
          <h3 class="review-author">Kevin Smith,</h3>
          <p class="role">Pediatrics student</p>
          <p class="review-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <img class="review-photo" src="img/kevin.png" alt="kevin's avatar" width="90" height="90"/>
        </li>
        <li class="review">
          <h3 class="review-author">Jane Lambert,</h3>
          <p class="role">Psychiatry student</p>
          <p class="review-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <img class="review-photo" src="img/jane.png" alt="jane's avatar" width="90" height="90"/>
        </li>
        <li class="review">
          <h3 class="review-author">Jane Lambert,</h3>
          <p class="role">Psychiatry student</p>
          <p class="review-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <img class="review-photo" src="img/jane.png" alt="jane's avatar" width="90" height="90"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! I think it's the answer :) As I understood correctly, `.testimonials` should stretch by its width  according to its content - is it possible to save the fixed width of `.testimonials` if it exists when `.testimonials` is overflowed?

Comment: @Gramin To grab an elements value you use script ... and will update my answer with an explanation