# Make "overflow: scroll" work with centering flex-box layout

Tags: css, flexbox

Consider the following example:

HTML

```
<div id="body">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="item-1"></div>
    <div id="item-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#body {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#item-1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

#item-2 {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black, white);
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

see also https://jsfiddle.net/nfzo3xfj/5/

I have a flex container with two items as a centered column. These items can grow larger than the surrounding `<div>` element, so I want to use `overflow: scroll` to enable scrolling in that case. However, scrolling only works in one direction (to the right side). How can I enable scrolling towards the left (black) side of the second item as well?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Also `overflow:overlay` is non-standard and not supported outside of Webkit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38830775/3597276