# Overflow auto not working with justify-content: flex-end

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get an element to have items aligned to the right, and all overflowing elements to be hidden but accessed by scrollbar.

But it seems like the scrollbar disappears when specifying `justify-content: flex-end`. Why is that, and how do I fix it?

Here is demo: https://jsfiddle.net/efguz4mp/1/

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #DADADA;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  background: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

...and here is demo without `justify-content: flex-end;`: https://jsfiddle.net/efguz4mp

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #DADADA;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  background: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When an overflow occur to the left (or top), a scroll doesn't get rendered, and the reason is that a HTML document's normal flow is left-to-right (top-to-bottom).

Flexbox has a *row-reverse* direction, which will solve that, thought 2 things comes with that:

- One need to reorder the items or use an inner wrapper
- I.a. Firefox and Edge doesn't show the scroll (possible bug)

Stack snippet

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #DADADA;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  overflow: auto;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  background: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

/* no wrapper */
.row > .box:nth-child(1) { order: 6; }
.row > .box:nth-child(2) { order: 5; }
.row > .box:nth-child(3) { order: 4; }
.row > .box:nth-child(4) { order: 3; }
.row > .box:nth-child(5) { order: 2; }
.row > .box:nth-child(6) { order: 1; }

/* wrapper */
.inner {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>

<div><br><br></div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Possible workarounds are:

- Use `direction: rtl` to change the flow direction

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #DADADA;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  direction: rtl;
}
.inner {
  display: flex;
  direction: ltr;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  background: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Use `transform` to flip the `row` element

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #DADADA;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  transform: scale(-1,1);        /*  flip horizontally  */
}
.inner {
  display: flex;
  transform: scale(-1,1);        /*  reset so items is not backwards  */
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  background: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- Use a script on page load to scroll to the right

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
  var el = document.querySelector(".row");
  el.scrollLeft = el.scrollWidth;
});
```

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #DADADA;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  background: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I understand how it works now, also thanks for the snippets :)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you're dealing with a contradiction:

- The [**`justify-content`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property) property is designed to distribute extra space in the container.
- However, an [**`overflow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) condition occurs when there is no space left in the container.

Basically, `justify-content` and `overflow` have no association. The former applies only *inside* the container. The latter applies only *outside* the container.

With `justify-content: flex-end`, the flex items must be packed at the end of the *container* (not the end of the `flex-start` overflow area).

If the end-aligned items are too big to fit in the container, they will overflow on the start side, which is what you're seeing in your layout. But because the `overflow` property only applies in the direction of the writing mode (LTR, in this case), scrollbars are not rendered ([more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38830775/3597276)).

So I would suggest forgetting about `justify-content` to make this layout work.

Instead, consider this: Use an invisible spacer item to push your content items to the right.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #DADADA;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  background: red;
}

.row::before {
  content: "";
  flex: 0 0 400px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

You'll notice that the last item margin collapses. That issue is explained here:

- [Last margin / padding collapsing in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38993170/3597276)

Answer (score -2):

Here's how I would recommend you do it

```css
.row {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #DADADA;
  flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    overflow: auto;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 4px 10px;
  background: red;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```