# Horizontal scroll with flex wrap-reverse doesn't work

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this code and I'm okay with it. But I have a problem with scrolling.

I want to give a width to the `.b` class and I want horizontal scroll.

I try to add this code to the `.b` class:

```
width: 500px;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

But it doesn't work. Is there a bug with flex wrap-reverse with scrolling?

This is an interesting case I think. Any idea for this problem?

NOTE: I need the orange boxes exactly where they are now. I cannot change order or wrap positions. I only need horizontal scroll.

```css
.a {
  width: 100%;
}

.b {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  height: 600px;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.c {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}

.w {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 5px;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="w">
      <span>AAAA</span>
      <span>1</span>
      <div class="c">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w">
      <span>AAAA</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <div class="c">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w">
      <span>AAAA</span>
      <span>3</span>
      <div class="c">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w">
      <span>AAAA</span>
      <span>4</span>
      <div class="c">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w">
      <span>AAAA</span>
      <span>5</span>
      <div class="c">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @javauser35 the wrapper element of .b should have less width than .b for the overflow css to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling in CSS is a function of the `overflow` property.

However, `overflow` only works in the direction of the text direction.

With `wrap-reverse` the flex items are laid out in a direction opposite the text direction (LTR), so `overflow` doesn't apply and scrollbars can't work.

More details and possible workarounds here:

- [Can a scroll bar appear for content overflowing the browser window to the left?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38830775/3597276)
- [Overflow auto not working with `justify-content: flex-end`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47377177/3597276)