# Flex container with flex-direction of row and flex-wrap of wrap-reverse is not scrollable on mobile

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent div with the following CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

and a couple of children with CSS of

```
.item {
    padding: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Used with the JSX ( React )

```
<div className="container">
            <div className="item">item 1</div>
            <div className="item">item 2</div>
            <div className="item">item 3</div>
            <div className="item">item 4</div>
            <div className="item">item 5</div>
            <div className="item">item 6</div>
            <div className="item">item 7</div>
            <div className="item">item 8</div>
            <div className="item">item 9</div>
            <div className="item">item 10</div>
        </div>
```

on Chrome Desktop items **will** overflow and parent gets **scrollable**, but on Chrome Mobile (iOS) it **does not** getting **scrollable** even with  `overflow-y: scroll;`

I tried adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` along with max-height to `.container`'s CSS but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47456577/3597276

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses `className` and that is not what is used in HTML to reference a CSS class and that is why the css is not being interpreted by the browser. You should use `class` instead, as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
    <div class="item">item 4</div>
    <div class="item">item 5</div>
    <div class="item">item 6</div>
    <div class="item">item 7</div>
    <div class="item">item 8</div>
    <div class="item">item 9</div>
    <div class="item">item 10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm using it with react, sorry for unclarity